# GEE Error generating chart: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'init')

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to draw an annual No2 chart, but I am getting this error:

> Computation timed out.

My Code:

```
var start_year = 2019
var end_year = 2023
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2")
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate(ee.Date(start_year + '-01-01'), ee.Date(end_year + '-12-31'))
  .filterBounds(roi)
var yearlyMeans = dataset.map(function(image) {
  var year = image.date().get('year')
  var mean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 1000,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  })
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'year': year,
    'NO2_mean': mean.get('NO2_column_number_density')
  })
})
var features = ee.FeatureCollection(yearlyMeans)
var chartData = features.reduceColumns({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList().repeat(2),
  selectors: ['year', 'NO2_mean']
})
var chart = ui.Chart.array.values({
    array: ee.List(chartData.get('list')),
    axis: 0,
    xLabels: ee.List(chartData.get('list')).slice(0, end_year - start_year + 1) // Yılları etiketle
  })
  .setChartType('LineChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Yıllık Ortalama NO2 Değerleri (' + start_year + '-' + end_year + ')',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Yıl'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Ortalama Değer'
    }
  })
print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/27e103f6422b23f994a0bb8392ad5b27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataset` collection contains `25718` images. You call `reduceRegion()` on every one of them. If you want yearly stats, you could instead create one composite for every year and `reduceRegion()` on those instead. The script below uses yearly median composites. It also simplify your code a bit by using a `ui.Chart.feature.byFeature()` chart.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2")
  .select('NO2_column_number_density')
  .filterDate(
    ee.Date.fromYMD(start_year, 1, 1), 
    ee.Date.fromYMD(end_year + 1, 1, 1) // Exclusive end date
  )
  .filterBounds(roi)
var yearlyMeans = ee.List.sequence(start_year, end_year).map(function(year) {
  var composite = dataset
    .filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year), 1, 1).getRange('year'))
    .median()
  var mean = composite.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 1113.2,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    tileScale: 16
  })
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'year': ee.Number(year).format('%d'),
    'NO2_mean': mean.get('NO2_column_number_density')
  })
})
var features = ee.FeatureCollection(yearlyMeans)
var chart = ui.Chart.feature
  .byFeature({
    features: features, 
    xProperty: 'year', 
    yProperties: 'NO2_mean'
  })
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e870eb33b4faadf4720616d5d62bbe81